# Percona mongod audit filter

Tags: mongodb, filter, ubuntu-14.04, audit, percona

I'm trying to use filters with ***auditLog***, and I'm currently facing an issue :

I'd like to print only commands like `"insert"`, `"delete"`, `"update"` from a precise database in my log file. I tried few things, but none of them worked out.
I went through ***Percona*** and ***Mongodb*** doc, and I found out that with ***Mongo Enterprise*** I'd have to use `"setParameter {auditAuthorizationSuccess: true}"` as parameter to get what I want.
But if I try using this in my ***mongod.conf*** file, or in command line, I have an error : `"Unrecognized option: setParameter { auditAuthorizationSuccess ".`
I tried to find anything about it in Persona doc, but I couldn't find an answer.

Here's the ***audit*** part of my ***mongod.conf*** file :

```
audit:
destination: file
format: JSON
path: /data/log/mongodb/vip-auditLog.json
filter: '{ atype: "authCheck", "users.db": "vip", "param.command": {$in: [ "insert", "delete", "update", "find", "findandmodify" ] } }'
setParameter { auditAuthorizationSuccess: true }
```

I'm using ***ubuntu : 14.04 LTS*** and ***percona server for mongodb : 3.0.10-1.5***.

I've already asked on percona forum, no answer there though the question is 1 month old.

Comment: Which version of mongodb? auditAuthorizationSuccess is available from v2.6.5 only.

Comment: Sorry if it isn't clear, I'm using percona server for mongodb, which provides the same audit functions as mongodb enterprise. I'm using the latest version fo percona server for mongodb : 3.0.10-1.5.

Comment: Just installed the percona one. Unfortunately I can only confirm it does not work. Neither from config, parameter, nor shell.

Comment: I issued a ticket on their Jira server a month ago, with no luck, I was hoping someone would know what to do here, but I feel like really few people are interested in audit with percona.